# Is it possible to color-code an email entry in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, colors

I would like to add conditional color codes to my emails in Outlook.

**What I know**: how to use the View entry to change the **font** of the entry (size, color, family)

**What I do not know**: how to color the background of the entry (so that it stands out) ← **is this possible?**

[image]

Comment: I'm unsure how I missed such blatant info, so I've removed the comment and will delete this one in 24hrs

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to color code an entry, but afaik only with "Follow up" option (right click -> Follow up). This will set the background to red. I use this to not miss important emails.

There is an option to add colored square to a category. I set colors to categories so I can quickly see what category it is in.

In this image you can see how this looks. It is not exactly what you want but this was the best I could find for my own needs.
[Outlook example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q00oU.png)

Comment: Unfortunately flagging an email for a follow-up does not change the background for me (Outlook 2019). It just adds a flag above the reception date/time. I use categories and their colors, but this only appears in the preview, not in the list of emails

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we could set a series of messages to other color/font like below, but it could only work for a series of message by the filterautomatically and we couldn't set it for a specific message mannually. For example, I have set all messages from Jade to red and bold in my message list:
[image]

If that's also meet your need, you could follow these steps to set it :View settings>conditional formatting>Add>set the font>choose the condition(Apart from sender field, there are also many other filters that we could set )

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I put in my question under "What I know"

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. In that case, I think there may be no option that could meet it in Outlook 2019, due to the red background of message as pormulsys mentioned by flag seems to could only work on Outlook 365.